# Get value of Deselected option Multiselect

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a form that has a 2 select boxes for dependent lists.

I'm loading a second list based on the value selected in the first list, which is multiselect.

```
<select id="list1" multiple='multiple'>
    <option value="a">a value</option>
    <option value="b">b value</option>
    <option value="c">c value</option>
</select>
<select id="list2">
</select>
```

For each option added to list2, I'm also adding a class with value of list1 corresponding to the list2 value.

For loading the elements for the selected option, I use the code:

```
$('#list1').on('change', function(){
    var list1vals = $('#list1').val().split(',');
    var newval = '';
    for(x in list1vals)
    {
        // Checking for selected value of list1 which doesn't have
        // corresponding values in list2.

        if($('.'+list1vals[x]).length == 0) 
        {
            newval = list1vals[x];
        }
    }
    $.ajax({
        type : "GET",
        url : "/xyz.php?action=getlist2&list1="+newval,
        success : function(response)
        {
            if($.trim(response) != '')
            {
                $('#list2').append(response);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

xyz.php

```
$action=$_GET['action'];
$listval1=$_GET['list1'];
switch($action)
{
    /////////////////

    case 'getlist2':
            $list2 = fetchlist2($list1val);
            foreach($list2 as $listobj)
            {
                $optionlist = '<option class="'.$list1val.'" value="'.$listobj['id'].'">'.$listobj['value'].'</option>';
            }
            echo $optionlist;
            break;

    ////////////////
}
```

Is there any way in which I can remove the element unselected in list1 from list2?

i.e when an option is unselected, I want to remove all elements in list2 having class value of the unselected element.

Note : The operation for fetching the list in `fetchlist2` is expensive and hence I want to handle removal of element in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im sorry if I was not able to express my problem properly.

These are 2 different lists, with the value of first list determining what was to be loaded in the second list, similar to selecting category and loading subcategory based on selected category.

I sort of figured out a way to do it. This is how I did what I wanted:

```
    var list1vals = ($('#list1').val()+'').split(',');
    var newval = '';
    for(x in list1vals)
    {
        /// Checking list2 elements to see 
        /// which list1 selected element is not present

        if($('.'+list1vals[x]).length == 0) 
        {
            newval = list1vals[x];
        }
    }
    if(newval == '')
    {
        /// Some Element removed, checking which
        /// options remain selected

        var options1,list2options = [];
        $('#list1 option:selected').each(function(){
            options1 = $('#list2 option[class="'+ $(this).val() +'"]');
            list2options.push(options1);
        });
        $('#list2').html('');
        $('#list2').append(list2options);
    }
    else
    {
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"/xyz.php?action=getlist2&list1="+newval,
        success:function(response)
        {
            selectbox = $('#list2');
            var list2 = $.parseJSON(response);

            /// Adding options returned for newval to list2
            /// with class set as newval

            for(x in list2)
            {
                var option = $('<option></option>');
                $(option).attr('value',list2[x].value);
                $(option).html(list2[x].value);
                $(option).addClass(newval);
                $(selectbox).append(option);
            }
        }
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

you could try this if you just want the unselected options from list1 to be removed from list2:

```
    $('#list1').change(function(){          
      var lists = $('#list1').val();
      var str = '';          
      if (lists != null){
        for(var i=0;i<lists.length;i++){
          str += '<option value="'+lists[i]+'">' + $('#list1 option[value="'+  lists[i]+'"]').text() + '</option>';
        }
      }
      $('#list2').html(str);          
    });
```

or if you just want to remove an option element with a class that is the value of the unselected element from list1:

```
$('#list1 option:not(:selected)').click(function(){           
   $('#list2 option[class="'+ $(this).val() +'"]').remove();
})
```

Comment: Sorry to respond after so long, but the content of the lists were separate and hence the first solution didn't work. The other solution didn't fit as well. I probably described my question too vaguely. Posted what I finally did.